# Bot for Teams with Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I wanted to develop a Bot for Teams with Graph API.

I referred many documentations , but still didn't get clear picture about this.

1. Can I build a bot with Graph API (in Teams) without explicit sign in. Since most of the articles are provided with Login option, I want something like single sign on when a bot is deployed in Teams.
2. If I build a bot in Azure with Graph API, how do i deploy it in Teams?

Please someone shed some light on this.

Thanks in Advance,

Sendil M

Comment: Please refer to this sample for Teams SSO: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/teams-sso/csharp_dotnetcore

Answer (score 2):

- With specific to building bot, [adding SSO with Teams/tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample), you can get it [started using the following documentation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/authentication-sso-and-microsoft-graph-in-microsoft-teams-tabs/ba-p/125366) and you can see the [Node.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node), [C# samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp).
- To [deploy/distribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/overview) the Bot in Microsoft Teams you can get it started from here.